# Disambiguate the audio=sound and video tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) (which has the synonym [sound](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound)) is used for at least two different purposes:

- Getting sound from an application to the physical world. This covers sound systems like PulseAudio, JACK, etc. as well as audio drivers and tools such as mixer and volume control.
- Manipulating files that represent sound, e.g. converting between sound file formats.

We should disambiguate these, as they are different topics that don't overlap so much. The sound system/driver meaning is predominant. What tag names should we choose? Are there other, less common meanings?

The tag [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) is muddier to me, I'm not certain whether it should be broken down and if so, how.

Answer (score 5):

I see no point in tagging questions about manipulating sound files as [audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio). They're not about audio as such, they're about format conversion. While audio formats are special and need particular tools to manage them, they are not really related to audio as such.

So, I suggest we tag audio file manipulation questions with say [audio-formats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-formats) and keep [audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) for managing the sound system, recording etc.